# How to avoid audio recording fade in?

Tags: fedora, audio, services, plasma5, recording

Audios recorded from the microphone start with a pop and a fade in. I tried 2 mics from two hardware inputs.

I found [this solution](https://leochavez.org/index.php/2020/04/11/fixing-unwanted-volume-fade-in-ubuntu/) that describes my problem but Fedora 35 has no `default.pa` file:

```
In the /etc/pulse/default.pa file, comment out this line:
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

> It seems this is just default Pulse Audio behavior and essentially tries to save resources by “dimming” sources of audio that become idle for “too long.” I haven’t really timed it to figure out how long “too long” is, but with the change above, it doesn’t matter anyway

What would be the Fedora 35 equivalent?

Indeed if I start recording immediately after another recording there is no fade in but the pop persists.

I found the `pipewire-pulse systemd` user unit but no obvious setting:

```
[Unit]
Description=PipeWire PulseAudio

# We require pipewire-pulse.socket to be active before starting the daemon, because
# while it is possible to use the service without the socket, it is not clear
# why it would be desirable.
#
# A user installing pipewire and doing `systemctl --user start pipewire-pulse`
# will not get the socket started, which might be confusing and problematic if
# the server is to be restarted later on, as the client autospawn feature
# might kick in. Also, a start of the socket unit will fail, adding to the
# confusion.
#
# After=pipewire-pulse.socket is not needed, as it is already implicit in the
# socket-service relationship, see systemd.socket(5).
Requires=pipewire-pulse.socket
ConditionUser=!root
Wants=pipewire.service pipewire-session-manager.service
After=pipewire.service pipewire-session-manager.service
Conflicts=pulseaudio.service

[Service]
LockPersonality=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
RestrictNamespaces=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallFilter=@system-service
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
Restart=on-failure
Slice=session.slice

[Install]
Also=pipewire-pulse.socket
WantedBy=default.target
```

`journalctl` shows this:

```
dez 31 15:21:15 d3.localdomain plasmashell[2950304]: 15:21:15: Debug: AudioIO::GetBestRate() for playback
dez 31 15:21:15 d3.localdomain plasmashell[2950304]: 15:21:15: Debug: GetBestRate() suggested rate 44100 Hz
dez 31 15:21:15 d3.localdomain plasmashell[2950304]: 15:21:15: Debug: GetBestRate() Returning 44100 Hz
```

Would it be Plasma adding the delay?

```
$ systemctl --user status session.slice
● session.slice - User Core Session Slice
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/session.slice; static)
     Active: active since Sat 2022-01-01 10:14:18 -03; 29min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
      Tasks: 95
     Memory: 638.7M
        CPU: 38.748s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice
             ├─at-spi-dbus-bus.service
             │ ├─2403 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
             │ ├─2409 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --scope user
             │ └─2410 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id 938e97f50c4f42609f51bf4ed43fe113 --max-bytes 100000000>
             ├─dbus-broker.service
             │ ├─1818 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope user
             │ └─1821 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 11 --machine-id 938e97f50c4f42609f51bf4ed43fe113 --max-bytes 10000000>
             ├─gvfs-daemon.service
             │ └─1862 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
             ├─gvfs-metadata.service
             │ └─4700 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
             ├─pipewire-pulse.service
             │ └─1804 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
             ├─pipewire.service
             │ └─1802 /usr/bin/pipewire
             ├─plasma-kded.service
             │ ├─2030 /usr/bin/kded5
             │ ├─4242 /usr/libexec/kf5/kioslave5 /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/kio_file.so file "" local:/run/user/1000/kde>
             │ └─4244 /usr/libexec/kf5/kioslave5 /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/kio_file.so file "" local:/run/user/1000/kde>
             ├─plasma-ksmserver.service
             │ └─2028 /usr/bin/ksmserver
             ├─plasma-kwin_x11.service
             │ └─2033 /usr/bin/kwin_x11 --replace
             ├─plasma-plasmashell.service
             │ ├─2071 /usr/bin/plasmashell --no-respawn
             │ ├─2678 /usr/bin/ksysguardd
             │ └─2843 /usr/libexec/kf5/kio_http_cache_cleaner
             ├─wireplumber.service
             │ └─1803 /usr/bin/wireplumber
             ├─xdg-desktop-portal.service
             │ └─2441 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
             └─xdg-document-portal.service
               ├─2445 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
               └─2453 fusermount -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=portal -- /run/user/1000/doc
```

Comment: I would suggest you start your investigations from the lowest possible level (bypassing all pulse fiddlings) using arecord on the appropriate alsa device.